# Why does an npm module I wrote install so many packages after creating project with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, nwb

I wrote this npm module, [react-heartbeat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-heartbeat), using [nwb](https://github.com/insin/nwb). When I install this module in a new project, `npm i react-heartbeat`, just after running `npm init` it takes less than 2 seconds and only installs 1 package. When I install this module, again `npm i react-heartbeat`, after creating a project with `create-react-app`, it takes nearly *3 minutes, adds 420 packages, removes 218 packages and updates 1257 packages*.

***What am I doing wrong?***

My npm module is very simple, just [1 React component](https://github.com/sayes2x/react-heartbeat/blob/master/src/index.js). It has no dependencies in the [`package.json`](https://github.com/sayes2x/react-heartbeat/blob/master/package.json) file. The following peer dependencies and dev dependencies that were created when nwb set the project up.

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "16.x"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/mocha": "^5.2.5",
  "nwb": "^0.23.0",
  "react": "^16.5.2",
  "react-dom": "^16.5.2"
},
```

I followed the instructions from nwb's [documentation](https://github.com/insin/nwb/blob/master/docs/guides/ReactComponents.md#building-and-publishing) to prepare my module for publishing (`npm run build`) and to publish my module (`npm publish`). The proper folders are white-listed in my `package.json`:

```
"files": [
  "es",
  "lib",
  "umd"
],
```

I ran `npm publish --dry-run` and confirmed that only the following 7 files are included in my project:

```
package.json
README.md
es/index.js
lib/index.js
umd/react-heartbeat.js
umd/react-heartbeat.min.js
umd/react-heartbeat.min.js.map
```

I am wondering if the problem is in the peer or dev dependencies, but I am not sure how to fix this.

Here is the source code for [react-heartbeat](https://github.com/sayes2x/react-heartbeat).
It can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-heartbeat) on npm.

Comment: I just tried installing `react-heartbeat` on a container on [Coder](https://coder.com) after creating a project using `create-react-app` and it only installed 1 package. So now I am wondering if the problem is with the Linux laptop I use to develop. Any suggestions on how to begin to troubleshoot this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create-react-app` is supposed to install it's dependencies but maybe it failed. Every time you run `npm i` it will install missing dependencies from `package.json`.

Make sure dependencies are installed before installing yours by running `npm i` and check nothing new.

Comment: That does seem to be the problem. When I ran `npm i` right after running `create-react-app` it installed 418 packages. Then I installed my mode module, and it only installed 1 package. Now I have to figure out why this is happening.